# Use async with void return for fire and forget in C#

Tags: c#, threadpool, async-await

I have a method return void in a Web APP

```
public static void doSomething(){
}
```

I like it become fire and forget by using `async` in c# 5.0, how?

Btw, if the `void doSomethingQuick()` is short-run method, whats the most resource saving method to fire and forget?

If the `void doSomethingSlow()` is a long-running method, whats the most resource saving method to fire and forget?

Comment: The point of async is that you **don't** forget.  Just use QueueUserWorkItem.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doSomething());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of async methods:

```
async void Foo()
async Task Bar()
async Task<T> Baz()
```

Note that only the two last can be (a)waited on. Foo in this example is for fire and forget scenarios. You have to remember that `async` in this case is just an indicator that the method may itself use `await`. Hence you can declare `async void doSomethingQuick()` and `async void doSomethingSlow()`. Just because a method returns a task does not mean it executes on a seperate thread. It may return a completed task.